# getline(cin, string) not giving expected output

Tags: cin, getline

Using c++14. I have read many posts regarding the problem.

If I run this code below, it jumps over the getline lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main_menu.h"

void MainMenu::AddTest()
{
    std::string courseName = "";
    std::string testName = "";
    std::string date = "";

    std::cout << "Enter course name: " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, courseName);

    std::cout << "Enter test name: " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, testName);

    std::cout << "Enter test date: " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, date);

    Test test(courseName, testName, date);
    tests.Add(test);

    std::cout << "Test registered : " << std::endl;
    tests.Print(test.id);
}
```

If I add cin ignore after each getline lines (example below how I implement it), it deletes some characters from the input strings and uses wrong variables to store them. Note that I have strings with whitespaces.

```
std::getline(std::cin, courseName); 
std::cin.ignore();
```

This is what I get:

```
Enter course name: 
History 2
Enter test name:     
History 2 exam
Enter test date: 
2017.01.02
Test registered : 
test id = 2, course name = , test name = istory 2, date = istory 2 exam
```

I also tried to flush cout, didn't help.

My Print function works like a charm, if I add courses manually from main, I get the expected output, so the problem is definitely the cin / getline.

```
Test registered : 
test id = 1, course name = History 2, test name = History 2 exam , date = 01.02.2017
```

I use getline as explained here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By using `cin.ignore` you are messing with the input itself. If you want to get rid of `\n` character you don't have to! `getline` will just do that automatically. So just don't use `ignore` function and the code will be fine.
This works:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string courseName = "";
   string testName = "";
   string date = "";

   cout << "Enter course name: " << std::endl;
   getline(std::cin, courseName);

   cout << "Enter test name: " << std::endl;
   getline(std::cin, testName);

   cout << "Enter test date: " << std::endl;
   getline(std::cin, date);

   cout << courseName << endl;
   cout << testName << endl;
   cout << date << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I don't use the cin.ignore, I never get to enter the cin itself. The program goes further to the next cout, without waiting for input. It basically lists my cout's, that is my initial problem. @Sinapse

Comment: `cin.ignore` will just pass one of your entered characters! Can you test the code above? What is your compiler?

Comment: Your code works, mine does not. The program won't wait for input. Please take a look at my original code on the top (the one without the cin.ignore), I don't see much of a difference. I use GDB clion btw.

Comment: Man you're confusing me! If this works why are you not using it! Just don't use the `cin.ignore`

Comment: Please read my post from the very top, then you understand. I am not using cin.ignore to start with. I realize, this doesn't work, the program won't wait for input, it jumps over my getline(cin, .....) lines and lists automatically the next cout. So I try to solve the problem by implementing cin.ignore. It helps, the program now stops and waits for input, but now all my input strings are messed up. So, 1. if I don't use cin.ignore, I don't have the possibility to give input. 2. if I use it, it messes with the entered text. Hope it is clear now, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I got these mate! My question was this: will the code above work FOR YOU? i.e. in a test dummy project. If yes: the problem is not with the `cin` stream maybe you are doing something else before the cin which results in this behavior.

Comment: Another thing, if you are using clion, try running the executable in a console outside of clion and see what happens. Also, GDB is a debugger, its not your compiler you are probably using gcc

Comment: Yes, it works in a test project, but not in the original one. Unfortunately the code is getting to big to be able to share here, so I need to investigate myself. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Your welcome, I think you should try to investigate things that are engaged with `cin` before the code reaches here. Maybe there are line breaks streamed in `cin` and that causes it to jump over `getline`s

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering an ancient question, but try clearing the input stream before you use all the `getline()`'s. It is possible that you have some extra returns in the buffer before you ask for input.

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```